# How to deal with Google Maps API calls inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of rectangular boundaries which I want to search for restaurants with Google Places API Javascript.

At first I thought about iterating through the boundaries array with a `for` loop. Issue is, in each iteration I'll be making an async API call and a `for` loop is a synchronous action.

Ideally I'd like to iterate through all boundaries with a one minute difference between each API call and finish once all boundaries have been searched, maybe with `setInterval` but I can't quite get my head around it.

How can I do this?

```
loopSearch(zoneBoundaries)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= zoneBoundaries.length; i++)
        {
            const self = this;

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(zoneBoundaries[i].sw),
                new google.maps.LatLng(zoneBoundaries[i].ne)
            );

            self.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(self.map);

            var request = { bounds: bounds, types: [ 'restaurant', 'bar'] };

            self.placesService.search(request, self.placesCallback);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One clean solution is to use Promise all and await along with map to iterate through the coordinates inside the zone boundary

```
await Promise.all(
  zoneBoundaries.map(async (val, index) => {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(zoneBoundaries[index].sw),
                new google.maps.LatLng(zoneBoundaries[index].ne)
            );

            self.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(self.map);

            var request = { bounds: bounds, types: [ 'restaurant', 'bar'] };
            const response = await self.placesService.search(request, self.placesCallback);
            const result = response.json()
            console.log(result)
  })
);
```

Advantage of using above approach is that `map` moves on to the next item as soon as a promise is returned and `Promise.all` waits until all of these promises are resolved.